# Are type qualifiers part of the type of an expression?

Tags: c, function, types, declaration, qualifiers

In C,

1. are type  qualifiers such as `const` , `volatile`,  `restrict` , and
   `_Atomic` part of the type of an expression?

   For example

   ```
   const int x = 3;
   ```

   Which is the type of `x`, `const int` or  `int`?
2. Does the type of a function include type qualfiers of its
   parameters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the C Standard there is written (6.2.5 Types)

> 26 Any type so far mentioned is an unqualified type. Each unqualified
>   type has several qualified versions of its type,47) corresponding to
>   the combinations of one, two, or all three of the const, volatile, and
>   restrict qualifiers. **The qualified or unqualified versions of a type
>   are distinct types** that belong to the same type category and have
>   the same representation and alignment requirements....

However according to function parameters for example these two declarations declare the same one function

```
void f( const int );
void f( int );
```

From the C Standard (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes))

> 15. ...(In the determination of type compatibility and of a composite type,
>       each parameter declared with function or array type is taken as
>       having the adjusted type and **each parameter declared with qualified
>       type is taken as having the unqualified version of its declared
>       type**.)

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( const int );

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 10;

    f( x );

    return 0;
}

void f( int x )
{
    printf( "The argument is %d\n", x );
}
```

Its output is

```
The argument is 10
```

Take into account that however a definition of a function can depend on whether its parameter declared with the qualifier `const` or without it.

Comment: Thank you. Where do you find "according to function parameters for example these two declarations declare the same one function"? what is the reason?

Comment: To help me make sense of this, I remember that  that function parameters are passed by value not by reference so the qualifiers on the parameter apply to the copy of the value seen by the function -- not to the source of the value in the caller.

Comment: Wait… oh, okay, I read it the wrong way around. I guess I'll just drop my comment then as it's misleading.